# Create random number and make sure it is unique

Tags: php

In my system each customer has its own folder, name of which is generated by rand() function.

I want to make sure that value of $random variable stays always unique. i have created bellow code which should:

1. Generate Random Number
2. Check If folder with unique value Exists
3. If exists generate new number
4. If doesn't exist mkdir with random value name

But i am not sure if it works as should and is efficient way of doing above steps.

```
$random = rand(pow(10, 3-1), pow(10, 3)-1);
$path_validator = 'build/'.$random;
if(is_dir($path_validator)) {
    $random = rand(pow(10, 3-1), pow(10, 3)-1);
}
else
{
   mkdir('build/crm/'.$random, 0777);
}
```

`$random` has to be random 3 digit number

Comment: "But i am not sure if it works as should and is efficient way of doing above steps." Yes it also look prone to very unlikely **race condition** when the `$random = rand(pow(10, 3-1), pow(10, 3)-1);` generates the same number when two client or more clients run it at the same time it's a small chance but you know the law of murphy  right? **Anything that can go wrong will go wrong**

Comment: I'm assuming the customer has it's own ID (in the database), right? Can you use the ID as the folder name? Otherwise, use a Guid like Tim proposed.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland , hmm you mean that if two or more people open the url at exact same time rand() will calculate the same number for both of them?, and since the folder is not created yet my validator will not work ? p.s. can all of them path mkdir() without error as well ?

Comment: @Devator , unfortunately not there is complex structure behind this simple question. folder is sub-domain and which is generated before user registration.

Comment: What will happen when you reach your 1,000th customer?

Comment: @Tim, it is demo environment where maximum number of testers/folders should be less than 1000.

Comment: "hmm you mean that if two or more people open the url at exact same time rand() will calculate the same number for both of them?" Yes that is what i meant.. By the way is this code connected to a database? I would let the database generate a number per customer_id , fast and race condition safe..

Comment: @Tim well I'd screw it all and go on holiday for a month to babados. Hell yeah! Customer 1001 can wait.

Comment: Use a database like i say before make it extendable then you don't have to rewrite the whole code to  support the 1001th customer like @Tim says.  MyISAM table engine can generate a number in and between groups in this case customer id  see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jfNPf3Ypv2v8kyZfAgZKYx/1) .. Wait did i just advice you use MyISAM well this is the only valid case where i would choose MyISAM over InnoDB because InnoDB does not support this feature.

Comment: @RaymondNijland upon reviewing my statement I find that modern versions of InnoDb does now have *most* of the features that MyISAM has.

Comment: "upon reviewing my statement I find that modern versions of InnoDb does now have most of the features that MyISAM has. " Yes InnoDB didn't support FULLTEXT indexes from the start pretty sure that was one of your points.. Also InnoDB is much faster then MyISAM in general sense when configured correctly because InnoDB data and indexes can be loaded into the memory where for MyISAM only the idnex is on the memory.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland, as mentioned previously there is much more behind this simple function which is bit complicated to explane in this format, there are reasons why i don't want to use database, in case of DB i could simple create 1000 records in advance and assign it based on active/inactive row statues. but your comment about MyISAM is highly appreciated it is most likely to solve my other issue for different project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one-liner :)

`while(!is_dir($id = uniqid()) && !mkdir($id));`

3 Digit-Number:

`while(!is_dir($id = rand(100,999)) && !mkdir($id));`

**EDIT (bulletproof - hopefully):**

`while(count(glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR))<899 && !@mkdir('sub.' . rand(100,999) . '.domain.com'));`

Explaination:

Will abort immediately if there are 899 directories present.

`@mkdir` to *try* to make a directory. If it fails, mkdir will return `false` so the loop goes on.

No more `is_dir` to prevent simultanious execution race condition.

Example:

Bob checks `is_dir('333')`

Joe checks `is_dir('333')`

Bob tries to create directory '333' - success.

Jeo tries to create directory '333'- fail.

Comment: `uniqid` returns numbers and lets as it uses hex values. OP wants numbers only and only 3 digits.

Comment: and what happens if there are already 300 files in one directory and the random keep randoming in the 1 - 300 range for example..

Comment: it will keep randoming until it gets a free spot - well if there is no free spot it will try forever... and ever. Thats why uniqid is the better choice

Comment: @Pilan , folder is sub-domain crm_***.example.org idea is to keep it simple and not more than 1000. that is why i need random 3 digit number. but infinite loop is not an option. i think i have to change something in my scheme.

Comment: "it will keep randoming until it gets a free spot " yes i know @Pilan that it will keep doing that..Bruteforcing untill you get a free one its not a smart algorithm in fact it can take more and more time the more files are added.. The code might be stuck for a hour when all but the last 5-10 numbers are given out assuming the time limit is not set.

Comment: Well, whats the option? You have to check. If you got a solution for this i'd be glad to hear it :) - I have one, but its not random anymore, if you could apply an algorythm to find a free spot, it wouldnt be random - see the problem? :D

Comment: Why do you add an error suppressor (`@`) to the `mkdir` function?

Comment: Because i dont want errors form mkdir if i hit a existing directory - i skipped the `is_dir` so the check is implicit now - i know it no poem anymore :D

Comment: But isn't that the core of the OP question to check if there is an existant directory and then re-roll the dice if so?

Comment: Thats what the code does. mkdir returns false if the directory exists - so the loop goes on - if i place the `is_dir` in there, there is a tiny tiny chance of a race condition there. Wanted to make it bulletproof :P

Answer (score 1):

## Qualifiers

**1)** Because you are already checking if the value exists, it's uniqueness doesn't really matter in terms of its comparitors.

**2)** Because you only want a "3 digit" number, there are only 1000 possibilities which makes the request for a *unique* value pretty meaningless, on the computing scale of things.

## The Answer

Therefore You can simply use [`mt_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) because:

> Many random number generators of older libcs have dubious or unknown characteristics and are slow. The mt_rand() function is a drop-in replacement for the older rand(). It uses a random number generator with known characteristics using the » Mersenne Twister, which will produce random numbers four times faster than what the average libc rand() provides.

And because you are looking for a set range of numbers you can simply set this range within the `mt_rand` function call.

Thus:

## Code

```
// Below lines are only to show the parts to generate $random var. 
// $random = mt_rand(0,999); //generate random number between 0 and 999
// $random = sprintf('%03d', $random); //forces value to 3-digits. ie: 005
//
// Real code begins here:
do {
    $random = sprintf('%03d',mt_rand(000,999));
    $path_validator = 'build/'.$random;
    clearstatcache(); // the directory checker result is cached.
}
while(is_dir($path_validator) || !mkdir('build/crm/'.$random, 0777));
```

(See also [`sprinf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php))

## Notes:

- The range is tiny -- 1000 iterations are miniscule. Square this number.
- Be extremely careful making folders with `0777` privileges.
- Be extremely careful of folder race-conditions where PHP can check for a folder's existance, and then find it doesn't exist before it is then created by a parallel* PHP process, such as another instance.
- When checking if a folder exists be careful with PHP [*Caching the results*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php).
- While `mt_rand` is *more random* than `rand` there is still a comparatively high likelihood that two users will both generate the same 3-digit values. Be warned!!

Comment: Also looks prone to very unlikely **race condition** when the `$random = mt_rand(000,999);`; generates the same number when two client or more clients run it at the same time it's a small chance i know but you know the law of murphy right? **Anything that can go wrong will go wrong**

Comment: Thats as likely as me getting immediately stroke by a ligh...... *lost connection*

Comment: @RaymondNijland I agree entirely, but this is the criteria set out by the OP. with only 1000 iterations there is a comparatively high chance of a clash.

Comment: "with only 1000 iterations there is a comparatively high chance of a clash" true i didn't even looked at the range which the topicstarter needed/wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a GUID. http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php

It will most probably be unique.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, forgot to mention that $random has to be random 3 digit number, updated my question!